# Ruby on Rails: Can I do a "link_to" to call a create action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How would I correctly call the create action from a link_to? I'm using REST (map.resources :recipes). Here's the create action:

```
def create
  recipe = Recipe.create(:name => "French fries")
  redirect_to recipe
end
```

For example, I thought something like this might work:

```
<%= link_to "Create a default recipe", recipe_path, :method => :post %>
```

I'm not sure if that's a recommended (or even correct) way to do it. Any idea?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

That should work if you substitute `recipes_path` for `recipe_path`.

If you look at the output of `rake routes`, you should see something like:

```
recipes GET /recipes(.:format) {:controller=>"recipes", :action=>"index"}
        POST /recipes(.:format) {:controller=>"recipes", :action=>"create"}
```

That's a clue that the URL helper ("recipes_path"), for the create action is made up from the controller name with `_path` tacked on the end, using `:method => :post`. The same path using `:method => :get` (which is the default) maps to the `index` action.

Remember this won't work if Javascript is disabled, because Rails is actually adding an on_click handler that creates a form to do the POST. Same goes for delete links with the `:confirm` option.

Comment: appreciate your nice explanation zetetic! thank you so much! :)